# Trying to export the data from the crawl to a csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I found this code online, and I want to use it, but I can't find a way to export the data collected to a csv file.

```
import urllib
import scrapy
import json
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "http://www.straitstimes.com/tags/malaysia-crimes"

html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# kill all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
   script.extract()    # rip it out

# get text
text = soup.body.get_text()

# break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
# break multi-headlines into a line each
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("    "))
# drop blank lines
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

print(text)
```

Comment: please post the output you want.

Comment: Take a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985454/how-to-export-data-from-a-beautifulsoup-scrape-to-a-csv-file

It's a very similar problem and the answer could help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export data from a beautifulsoup scrape to a csv file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985454/how-to-export-data-from-a-beautifulsoup-scrape-to-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 0):

The below appears to work for what i believe you want:

I used the xlwt package to create, write to and save the workbook and then a loop to go through each line of text and write it to the workbook.  I saved it as testing.csv

```
import urllib
import scrapy
import json
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from xlwt import Workbook


url = "http://www.straitstimes.com/tags/malaysia-crimes"

html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# create excel workbook
wb = Workbook()
sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('Sheet 1')

# kill all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
   script.extract()    # rip it out

# get text
text = soup.body.get_text()

# break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
# break multi-headlines into a line each
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("    "))
# drop blank lines
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

print(text)

# go through each line and print to a new row in excel
counter = 1
for text_to_write in text.splitlines():
   sheet1.write(counter,1,text_to_write)
   counter = counter + 1

wb.save('testing.csv')
```